# Regex: don't match if the pattern start with /

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

My regex (PCRE):

```
\b([\w-.]*error)\b(?:[^-\/.]|\.\W|\.$|$)
```

is a match (the actual match is surrounded by stars) :

```
**this.is.an.error**  
**this.IsAnerror**  
**this.is.an.error**.  
**this.is.an.error**(  
bla **this_is-an-error**  
**this.is.an.error**:  
this is an (**error**)
```

not a match:

```
this.is.an.error.but.dont.match  
this.is.an.error-but.dont.match  
this.is.an.error/but.dont.match  
this.is.an.error/  
/this.is.an.error
```

for this sample: `/this.is.an.error`
I can't manage to have a condition that will reject the whole match if it starts with the character `/`.
every combination I've tried resulted in some partial catch (which is not the desired).

Is there any simple or fancy way to do that?

Comment: What language or environment are you implementing this regex in?

Comment: What that regex is supposed to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add lookabehinds at the beginning instead of a word boundary:

```
(?<!\/)(?<=[^\w-.])([\w-.]*error)\b(?:[^-\/.]|\.\W|\.$|$)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<!\/)` - negative lookbehind assuring there is no `/` before the first character;
- `(?<=[^\w-.])` - word boundary implementation taking into account your extended definition of characters accepted for a word `[\w-.]`;

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tBEMY/1)

Answer (score 1):

Prepend your regex with `\/.*|`:

```
\/.*|\b([\w-.]*error)\b(?=[^-\/.]|(?:\.\W?)?$)
```

Now just like before the first capturing group holds the desired part.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/AHDm5F/9)

Note: I made some modifications to your regex to remove unnecessary alternations.

Comment: it will also not match some legal phrase like : /   this.is.an.error

Comment: You didn't talk about that kind of pattern either.